# What is the difference between Run and Quick Run in jsperf

Tags: javascript, casting, boolean, jsperf

I found out a result than my code show different outcome when run/quick run

To be more accurate [here is my tests](https://jsperf.app/rupoxi)

So can anyone explain the difference between run and quick run?

Comment: Run seems to be using ~60 samples, whereas quick run uses ~10?

Comment: Correction, please look at https://github.com/rd13/jsperf.app/blob/main/components/TestRunner.js#L107. Run uses a timeout of 5, whereas quick run uses 0.5.